# Numba installation and "make check-all"

Tags: makefile, numba

I have been trying to install numba in a virtual environment. Numba requires llvm and what seems to be a Python wrapper of llvmpy. I successfully installed it using the [following steps](https://groups.google.com/a/continuum.io/forum/#!msg/numba-users/JWUIGi_BD0Y/HYCOkapfSlcJ):

```
wget http://llvm.org/releases/3.2/llvm-3.2.src.tar.gz
tar zxvf llvm-3.2.src.tar.gz
cd llvm-3.2.src
./configure --enable-optimized --prefix=/opt
REQUIRES_RTTI=1 make
make check-all
sudo REQUIRES_RTTI=1 make install

git clone git://github.com/llvmpy/llvmpy.git
cd llvmpy
sudo LLVM_CONFIG_PATH=/opt/bin/llvm-config /path/to/environment/bin/python setup.py install

python -c "import llvm; llvm.test()"
```

However, I would like to know what is the correct procedure. For example, in the line `REQUIRES_RTTI=1 make` and `sudo REQUIRES_RTTI=1 make install`, the variable REQUIRES_RTTI is repeated. Is it necessary?

According to the documentation of numba, it recommends to execute `REQUIRES_RTTI=1 make install` and llvmpy recommends `REQUIRES_RTTI=1 make`, so there are slight differences. I don't really know what each step is doing so I would appreciate a general explanation of what is going on and if all these steps are strictly necessary.

Furthermore, what is `make check-all`? I have seen it is particularly relevant in questions related to llvm but I don't know what is its purpose.

Another suggestion from llvmpy's documentation is to install using a different directory (--prefix) Why is that the recommended approach?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following lines

```
REQUIRES_RTTI=1 make
sudo REQUIRES_RTTI=1 make install
```

use the way of setting up environment of the called process without modifying the environment of the calee (like in case of export REQUIRES_RTTI=1); from [bash manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Environment):

> The environment for any simple command or function may be augmented
>   temporarily by prefixing it with parameter assignments. These assignment statements affect only the
>   environment seen by that command.

This setting is recommended because from [LLVM docs](http://llvm.org/docs/Packaging.html):

> Add REQUIRES_RTTI=1 to your environment
>   while running make to re-enable it. This will allow users to build
>   with RTTI enabled and still inherit from LLVM classes.

and according to llvmpy docs, RTTI is required.

So, forgetting this "complication" and standard requirement to use "sudo" for installing, the steps are standard:

```
### generating makefile:
./configure --enable-optimized --prefix=/opt
### building core libraries (make without target is the same as "make all")
make
### check-all is a makefile target that is used to run regression tests (according to LLVM docs) 
make check-all
### installing the libraries to the place where other tools / libraries can find them:
make install
```

Comment: Great explanation. A couple of questions. Do I need to add REQUIRES_RTTI=1 in both make and make install? Then those instructions that only write "REQUIRES_RTTI=1 make install" are wrong?

Comment: @RobertSmith I took a look into makefile.rules and found that this env. var. only affects compilation flags (i.e. "make" stage). So, most probably you are right (that make install do not need setting REQUIRES_RTTI), but I can't be 100% sure without testing both ways and comparing.